# Problem with BMI calculation program - if else and calculation errors in dev C++

Tags: c, if-statement

For some reason, it doesn't let me insert the weight data, prints only the ''short man'' category (regardless of height data inserted), doesn't print BMI'S value and completely ignores the last ''if else'' statement. I can't seem to find the problem as it looks perfectly fine to me. I'm using dev c++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char gender;
    float height;
    float weight;
    int category;
    float BMI;
    
    printf(" Enter gender: ");
    scanf("%c", &gender);
    printf(" Enter height: ");
    scanf(" %.2f", &height);
    printf(" Enter weight: \n");
    scanf(" %.1f", &weight);
           
    
    if ((gender == 'M'|| gender == 'm') && (height < 1.70 ))
    {
            category = 1;
            printf("Short man\n");
     }
    else if ((gender == 'M'|| gender == 'm') && (height >= 1.70 && height< 1.85))
         {
             category = 2;
             printf("Average man\n");
         }
    else if ((gender == 'M'|| gender == 'm') && (height >= 1.85))
         {
            category = 3;
            printf("Tall man\n");
         }
     
     else if (( gender == 'F' || gender == 'f' ) && (height < 1.60))
     {
              category = 4;
              printf("Short woman\n");
          }
    else if (( gender == 'F' || gender == 'f' ) && (height >= 1.60 && height <1.75))
          {
              category = 5;
              printf("Average woman\n");
          }
    else if (( gender == 'F' || gender == 'f' ) && (height >= 1.70))
          { 
            category = 6;
            printf("Tall woman\n");
          }
    
     
     switch(category)
     {
        case 1:
        {
           printf("Belongs to first category ");
         }
        break;
         
         
        case 2:
        {
            printf("Belongs to second category ");
        }
        break;
        
        case 3:
        {
             printf("Belongs to third category ");
        }
        break;
        
        case 4:
        {
            printf("Belongs to fourth category ");
        }
        break;
        
        case 5:
        {
            printf("Belongs to fifth category ");
        }
        break;
        
        case 6:
        { 
             printf("Belongs to sixth category ");
        }
        break;
     }
     
     BMI = (weight / (height * height));
     printf(" BMI is:, %.1f \n", BMI);
     
     if ( BMI <= 18.5)
     {
        printf("Underweight\n");
     }
     else if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI<= 25)
     {
        printf("Normal\n");
     }
     else if (BMI > 25 && BMI <=30)
     {
        printf("Overweight\n");
     }
     else if (BMI > 30)
     {
        printf("Obese\n");
     }
     
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `scanf(" %.2f", &height);` (and the next line) please change to `scanf(" %f", &height);` The `.2` is for `printf` not `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf(" %.2f"` ->  `scanf("%f"`

Comment: It can skip the last `else if` because that condition can be true for the previous test. Did you mean `1.70` to be `1.75` (typo)? If that is the last condition you don't need to check the height anyway. Generally, you don't need to repeat a test you have already done, for example further up, you have `height >= 1.60` but you already know that from `height < 1.60` in the previous test, and you are using `else`. Less repetition means less opportunity for typos, and easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes the ''1.70'' is a typo. Turns out I just had to change the scanf thing. It's an uni assignment, all this repetition etc is asked. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

the following program:

1. cleanly compiles
2. is consistently indented
3. contains 'some' optimization
4. makes use of `toupper()` to simplify `if()` statements
5. uses proper 'input format conversion' specifiers
6. performs the desired functionality
7. clarifies the prompts to the user
8. properly checks for errors
9. properly declares literals as 'float' via trailing 'f'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>  // toupper()

int main(void) 
{
    char gender = '-';
    float height = 0.0f;
    float weight = 0.0f;
    
    printf(" Enter gender: M or F ");
    if( scanf("%c", &gender) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "scanf for gender failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    gender = (char)toupper( gender );
    
    if( gender != 'M' && gender != 'Y' )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", "gender must be M or Y" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    
    printf("Enter height: in meters ");
    if( scanf("%f", &height) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "scanf for height failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    printf("Enter weight: in KG ");
    if( scanf("%f", &weight) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "scanf for weight failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
           
    int category = 0;
    
    if ( gender == 'M' )
    {
        if( height < 1.70f )
        {
            category = 1;
            printf("%s\n", "Short man");
        }
        
        if ( height >= 1.70f && height < 1.85f )
        {
            category = 2;
            printf("%s\n", "Average man");
        }
    
        if ( height >= 1.85f )
        {
            category = 3;
            printf("%s\n", "Tall man");
        }
    } // end male calculation of category
    
    if( gender == 'F' )
    {
        if ( height < 1.60f )
        {
            category = 4;
            printf("%s\n", "Short woman");
        }
    
        if ( height >= 1.60f && height <1.75f )
        {
            category = 5;
            printf("%s\n", "Average woman");
        }
    
        if ( height >= 1.70f )
        { 
            category = 6;
            printf("%s\n", "Tall woman\n");
        }
    }  // end calculation of category for female
     
     
    switch(category)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("%s\n", "Belongs to first category");
        break;
         
        case 2:
            printf("%s\n", "Belongs to second category");
        break;
        
        case 3:
            printf("%s\n", "Belongs to third category");
        break;
        
        case 4:
            printf("%s\n", "Belongs to fourth category");
        break;
        
        case 5:
            printf("%s\n", "Belongs to fifth category");
        break;
        
        case 6:
            printf("%s\n", "Belongs to sixth category");
        break;
    }
    
    float BMI = (weight / (height * height));
    printf("%s\n", "BMI is: %.1f", BMI);
     
     
    if ( BMI <= 18.5f )
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Underweight");
    }
    
    else if ( BMI > 18.5f && BMI <= 25.0f )
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Normal");
    }
     
    else if ( BMI > 25.0f && BMI <= 30.0f )
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Overweight");
    }
    
    else if ( BMI > 30.0f )
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Obese\n");
    }
     
     
    return 0;
}
```